# SQL-Server datetime not nullable no default value set

Tags: sql-server

If a field's datatype is a datetime, and does not allow nulls and there is no default value set, does the database enter the current timestamp?? I queried both here and MSDN but could not find an answer to this. Thanks.

Comment: It will only enter the current timestamp if you've set a default to do so (that is typically the purpose of a default for a datetime column). This is something you probably could have tried yourself faster than it took you to search MSDN or post this question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You need to provide a value for the column unless you specify a default value for the column.

Answer (score 1):

No. Typically the `INSERT` fails. You need to provide a default, or include a value for the column in your `INSERT` statement.